# Running swagger mock server using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am using Sails.js and swagger. To start the mock server I run

```
swagger project start -m
```

and it works fine, but it requires keeping the terminal open. So to daemonize I tried pm2 or even forever but they don't work (using Linux). The process.json for pm2 is:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "my-web-api",
            "script": "/usr/lib/node_modules/swagger/bin/swagger.js",
            "watch": true,
            "instances": "max",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "args": "['project', 'start', '-m']"
        }
    ]
}
```

The command:

```
p2 start process.json
```

doesn't start the server. `pm2 logs` command shows

```
PM2        | Script /usr/lib/node_modules/swagger/bin/swagger.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with pm2 still, check out prism http://stoplight.io/platform/prism. You can download it here for free: https://github.com/stoplightio/prism

This command line is all you need:

./prism run --mock --list --spec

The mock server will return dynamic response based on the swagger spec. If examples are provided in the spec, prism will return them, if not it will generate dummy data based on the spec.

Comment: Looks like this option "run" is outdated and no longer available in the newest version of prism. Apparently it has been replaced by "mock", but I have not found any replacement for "--list".